# Local Copy of Data for a project

Tags: qgis

We have an internal GIS library which has a very wide range of data from numerous sources.  We use this to supplement information provided by a client.  Our internal GIS files have coverage for the country, however for specific projects I only need a small subsection of the data.

At the start of a project I like to consolidate all of the information togethor. Is there a method to quickly copy an extract of the data to the project directory - to minimise the data set and speed up the work and also to make a copy for the records.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Grab the [QConsolidate](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/qconsolidate/) plugin. It will copy all the layers in the project into a single `layers` folder and update the project to look at that local path.

> Consolidate QGIS project into one directory

Just look for "consolidate" in the plugin installer.